# Requirements for full destructive reentry?

Tags: reentry

I was just wondering what variables are involved in a dead satellite deorbiting and fully burning up in the atmosphere. How much does mass/density/entry angle/velocity matter in the situation? If you were purposefully deorbiting something for destructive reentry, what would the ideal conditions be?

Comment: *"If you were purposefully deorbiting something for destructive reentry, what would the ideal conditions be?"*  Break it into small pieces (which burn faster) and have it enter the atmosphere in a shallow angle (but deep enough that the pieces don't bounce back off the upper reaches of the atmosphere)  to maximize the heat load on the parts.  (Generally though, I suspect this question is 'too broad' for an SO site.)

Comment: Angle velocity is very important. If it's tumbling, it will burn faster.

Comment: The nature of the object is far more important.

Answer (score 8):

Re-entry and orbital debris analysis is complex. Here is the [NASA standard for Orbital Debris Mitigation](http://orbitaldebris.jsc.nasa.gov/mitigate/technicalstandard.html). For US launches, satellite operators are required to submit a document known as an Orbital Debris Assessment Report (ODAR), an analysis that shows a spacecraft will enter autonomously before 25 years on orbit (for LEO spacecraft), and that there is a small probability of re-entry hazard.

This analysis is performed, in part, by using a NASA provided tool known as [Debris Assessment Software](http://orbitaldebris.jsc.nasa.gov/mitigate/das.html).

Here is an example of an ODAR for the [Skycube 1U cubesat](http://www.southernstars.com/skycube/files/SkyCube%20ODAR.pdf).